# sbt publishSigned on Sonatype Nexus via Travis CI with using pgpPassphrase

Tags: sbt, travis-ci, gnupg, pgp, sonatype

I've build an OSS project https://github.com/datlinq/scalafiniti 
The [Travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/datlinq/scalafiniti) pipeline works perfectly, but for 1 final step.

I followed these guides:

- http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Using-Sonatype.html
- http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-pgp/usage.html
- https://github.com/xerial/sbt-sonatype

Locally I got all steps working fine and actually published to the Nexus.

In the `.travis.yml` I import the key before install (Encrypted in travis.ci env)

```yaml
before_install:
 - echo "$PGP_SECRET" | base64 --decode | gpg --import
 - echo "$PGP_TRUST" | base64 --decode | gpg --import-ownertrust
```

The `$PGP_PASS` is also encrypted in Travis env and available for the `build.sbt`

I checked it actually gets the key in this command

```scala
pgpPassphrase := sys.env.get("PGP_PASS").map(_.toArray)
```

Now if Travis runs the command

`sbt publishSigned`

It still prompts for a passphrase for my key

> You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for user:
>   "com.datlinq.datalabs (Key for Datalabs OSS) "
>   2048-bit RSA key, ID 305DA15D, created 2017-09-01
>
> Enter passphrase:

I don't know what I should do to make this work

This moment in time is captured:

code:
https://github.com/datlinq/scalafiniti/tree/0d8a6a92bf111bae2a1081b17005a649f8fd00c9
build log: 
https://travis-ci.org/datlinq/scalafiniti/builds/271328874

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the reason it prompted for a password and ignored all sbt based configurations was due to the fact the build script used the local gnupg installation instead of the one packaged with sbt-pgp (bouncy castle). 
The local gpg wants you to manually enter the password the first time. A bit hard using TravisCI

So the solution was ignore the local gpg and use the bundled one, that uses the `pgpPassphrase` setting

Looking back to the documentation:

- http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-pgp/usage.html

In one of the first lines it actual says:

> **If you’re using the built-in Bouncy Castle PGP implementation, skip this step.**
>
> The first step towards using the GPG command line tool is to make sbt-pgp gpg->aware.
>
> `useGpg := true`

So the solution was to set `useGpg := false`

For more details look at the current repo:
https://github.com/datlinq/scalafiniti

Or check this blog (which I found later) https://alexn.org/blog/2017/08/16/automatic-releases-sbt-travis.html